# How to create IFC Files from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, export, ifc

I want to export my 3D-Modell(simple vectors and points) to a IFC-File using JavaScript.

Does anybody know libraries I can use for it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ifc.js](https://ifcjs.io/) to create IFC files, its a new library and has a lot of capabilities.

It has 3 parts in total - web-ifc, web-ifc-three & web-ifc-viewer. You need to use [web-ifc](https://ifcjs.github.io/info/docs/Guide/web-ifc/Introduction) to create IFC files.

Below is a quote from their website:

> It can edit data and write entire IFCs from scratch. Create apps that communicate with the large software vendors.